# AngularJS - Scope not applied in view within controller's function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, scope, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to modify a variable inside $scope within a controller's function and the affectation works, but didn't apply in the view.

```
app.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.test = "test";

    $scope.logIn = function() {
        // This changes the value to test2, but does not applies it to the view.
        $scope.test = "test2";
    };

}]);
```

In the login.html:

```
  DEBUG: {{ test }}
```

And the routeProvider:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/views/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    })
```

Is something I miss out the documentation ?

Thanks !

Comment: Can you please provide a Plunker with a demo of the problem. It's working for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/xbZWsE2i422BrDLDYXI3?p=preview

Comment: Please at least include the full HTML. No way to tell if you've assigned `ng-controller` or `ng-app` correctly.

Comment: Your code does not demonstrate that the `logIn` function is actually getting called to change value on the scope.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. how did you get through this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think this is a reference or inheritance issue that is known with primitives see this post https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes.  Try this same code but put *test* inside an object like so:

```
$scope.viewModel = {};
$scope.viewModel.test = 'Test';
```

Comment: This doesn't fix my issue. Thank you anyway !

Answer (score 3):

This happens because angular is not aware of the scope changes made by logIn function which i think is called asynchronously in your case. After calling logIn() asynchronously, force scope changes by

```
$scope.$apply()
```

Comment: Where should it be placed ? Cause in this case, it means I have to apply every HTTP responses with it ?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I put ng-controller="" in the HTML element that calls the logIn() function.

In fact, I called it twice and causes the view update to fail.